# Regular Expression to find out <a> tag and get the value of HREF using C#

Tags: c#, .net

can someone please help me for below

I have a string which stores html, need to find the  anchor tag and get the value of href of that tag using C#

For Example:

```
<p>can someone please help me for below </p>
<p>for Link <a href="www.ffb.cc">Click Here</a></p>
```

I need to get the href value ..generic code appreciated

Edit:

Tried `<a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href="([^"]*)"`

but no matches found

Note: I am unable to post the pic due to Reputation points :(

Comment: Have you tried to google your title before posting a question here?

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I Tried <a\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href="([^"]*)" but it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [Regex to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2345956). A correct way would be using an html parser like [HmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlstring);

var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a")
               .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value)
               .ToList();
```